# how to run linshed simulator?

Tags: scheduler

I'm trying to developed multi-core scheduling algorithm. For that, I need a linshed simulator. I cloned it to my PC. But there aren't many details about how to run the simulator.

Comment: What is a "linshed simulator?"  Do you mean the [Linux Scheduler Simulator](https://github.com/jontore/LinSched), or something else?  Do you have a link to the simulator you're referring to?

Answer (score 2):

LinSched can be built with a 32bits OS.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jontore/LinSched
$ cd LinSched/
$ make

Using : $ ./linsched
```

---

EDIT : Good news. The 32bits package, `linsched_2632-1_i386.deb`, installs OK and works OK with a 64bits OS → Tested with Ubuntu 16.04 - 64.

Link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNc3ExQjVPRUtrVU0/view?usp=sharing